# Assign links and classes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, location, append, attr

I have a site that is in English and Spanish, and in each page of the site there is a link that leads to the Spanish version of that specific page, so if the user were on the "home.php" page, it would look like this:

```
<div id="language">
    <ul class="language">
        <li class="english"><a href="#" class="active" title="English"></a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="spanish"><a href="inicio.php" class="notactive" title="Español"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is leave the href and the class in the `<a>` tags in the HTML blank and assign a class and an href URL to the `<a>` depending on the page the user is on, that way I could, for example, just add that language div to an external file, and use an `<include>` to attach it to each page. To accomplish this I'm using the following code:

```
$('ul.menubar a').each(function(){
    if(location.href.match('home.php')){
        $('ul.language li.english a').addClass('active');
        $('ul.language li.english a').append(function() {
            $(this).attr('onclick', 'return false;');
        });
        $('ul.language li.spanish a').addClass('notactive');
        $('ul.language a[href!="home.php"]').append(function() {
            $(this).attr('href', 'inicio.php');
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that the English version of the site has 4 links in the navigation bar (home.php, services.php, aboutus.php, contact.php), and the Spanish version likewise (with the corresponding translation of the URL names).  I think that having to repeat that code 8 times (1 for each link, 4 links in each language) would be excessive and would actually add more code than simply adding the class and href url in the HTML. The point of using JS would be to simplify things.

So I basically would like to know if anyone can think of a better way to do this, that wouldn't require that much code. I'm trying to avoid having to, in the event that I'd need to change something, have to edit each different page. Also, I would like to know if this is the best way to achieve want I want to do using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is best suited for managing content. CSS is best suited for presenting that content, and JavaScript is best suited for determining how that content behaves. Instead of trying to inject links and control the HTML from JavaScript; instead, leave the content where it belongs, inside the HTML, and use JavaScript to define one or two event-handlers to take action based on the class values on the hyperlinks themselves.

You already have a class on your English hyperlinks, and a separate class on your Spanish hyperlinks, so you can use this to your advantage.

### **Writing the Click Handlers:**

Since toggling your "Language switch" most likely causes a boolean value to be set, you can use two click handlers to target all of your English links and all of your Spanish links, and then control the *behavior* based on the value of that switch at the time the links are clicked.

```
// handler for all English links
$('li.english a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(/* Switch is english */) {
        window.location = $(this).attr("href");
    } 
});

// handler for all Spanish links
$('li.spanish a').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(/* Switch is SPANISH */) {
        window.location = $(this).attr("href");
    } 
});
```

Note that when a link is clicked, we first check the switch. Depending on it's value, we either redirect to that hyperlink, or simply prevent the default behavior -- going to a new page -- from completing.

### **Handling the Presentation:**

Now, your other problem is going to be that, assuming your Spanish site and your English site are one in the same, you'll now see 8 hyperlinks in total. Again, this is where your switch can come in handy.

```
// single handedly hide or display the relevant content, based on the switch
function switchToEnglish() {
    $('.english').show();
    $('.spanish').hide();
}

function switchToSpanish() {
    $('.spanish').show();
    $('.english').hide();
}
```

Now, I don't know what else is contained in your switch function, but the general idea here is that we don't need to *modify* the content. We just need to *show* and *hide* the content. You'd need to integrate this concept into your existing switch function, if you don't already have something like this in place.

**There are several advantages in this approach:**

- Your Web designers will still see href's in the HTML and can read and understand the HTML without needing your help or needing to go and look at JavaScript code. Not only will they see familiar patterns that they're used to seeing, but you'll likely have a better working relationship with them.
- Search engines spidering your site will be able to read the links and follow them.
- Browsers without JavaScript will be able to process the links. Some people seem to care about this. I don't. But it's worth mentioning anyway.

In summary, you're right about it being easier to manage in HTML. By using this technique, you can eliminate the repetition in the code that you're rightfully concerned about, and also move the content back to the HTML, as your gut is telling you is the correct thing to do. Not only will your code be more readable, but you'll get better SEO results as well.

Comment: Well, I do appreciate the answer, although I think I might have actually made a mistake using the term "switch". I was referring to having the site switch languages, and not to the Javascript term "switch". Basically clicking on the links leads to the spanish site, that was the whole point of it all. I'll edit and use a different term to avoid confusion. At any rate, I'm considering just leaving the links in the html, I just wanted to try to avoid unnecessary repetition, and use whatever is shorter, and therefore, if I wanted to change something, only have to change it in one place.

Comment: Definitely leave the links in the HTML. If in the JavaScript, you'd still have to change them twice (although in the same place), but you'd lose the SEO benefit of having them be spidered. Aside from that, if you're using an HTML templating system, you could have a common header with all your links in the HTML, and then use the CSS show/hide trick to show the relevant content. The links would be in 1 spot, and you'd still get the SEO benefit.